# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I try to modify a string constant?

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

I expect the output of this program to be: ibjgsjfoet
But i am getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char *p="haifriends",*p1;
    p1=p;
    while(*p!='\0')
    ++*p++;
    printf("%s   %s",p,p1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What made you think that `++*p++` was a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string literal:

```
char *p="haifriends";
++*p;
```

Usually, string literals are allocated in non writable memory, hence the segfault.

Answer (score 10):

> I expect the output of this program to be: ibjgsjfoet

```
char *p="haifriends",*p1;
```

`haifriends` resides in read only section of the memory and cannot be modified. If you wish to modify the string literal then you have to make a copy.

```
char p[]="haifriends",*p1;
p1 = p;
```

Answer (score 7):

Using two autoincrements in the same statement is asking for trouble.  Don't try to be tricky.  Write your code so that it is clear and expressive, and you'll get much better results.

Comment: If he didn't use two increments in the same statement, he'd still be causing the segfault, so this "answer" is completely unrelated to the question. Style advice belongs in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The memory region in which `p` lies cannot be written to. You can only modify memory you've `malloc`ed or which lies on the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[11];
    char *p,*p1;

    strcpy(buffer, "haifriends");
    p = &buffer[0];

    p1=p;
    while(*p!='\0')
    ++*p++;
    printf("%s   %s",p,p1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is in no way good practice but I hope this example code clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char p[11]="haifriends";
    char *p1;
    p1=p;
    while(*p1!='\0')
    ++*p1++;
    printf("%s   %s",p,p1);
    return 0;
}
```

Most compilers issue a warning on conversion from constant string to char*

Comment: That's not true, most compilers may *complain* about the conversion from string literal to `char *` but they will allow it. This is because string literals in C have type `char[N]` as opposed to `const char[N]` (where N is the length including NULL terminator)

Comment: Well, yes. you're right.. got the word wrong! Editing...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `*p="haifriends"` to `p[]="haifriends"`. Iirc you aren't allowed to modify string literals that are assigned to a regular character pointer, but you are when they're assigned to an array of characters.

<strike>Also `++*p++;` is undefined behavior. Try `*p++;p++;`, or maybe `++*(p++);` if that wouldn't also be undefined behavior (pretty sure it would be, though).</strike>

According to Michael, `++*p++;` isn't undefined behavior, but I would still recommend going with `*p++;p++;` or `++*(p++);` for clarification, as he agrees on that being a good idea.

Comment: `*p += 2` is not the same as `++*p++`.

Comment: Oh, woops, I suppose you're right. fixed. ...Or are multiple increments in the same statement allowed when a variable is a pointer? Is `++*p++;` equivalent to `++*(p++);`?

Comment: @Linus No, but that's because ++*p++ means "crash and burn". It is undefined behavior, there is no logic translation for what it will do in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it's undefined. But still not that undefined so it would advance the pointer twice?

Comment: @Linus Oh that's perfectly fine. The program may do _anything_ when it encounters undefined behavior.

Comment: @Linus: My replacement was meant for what user302520 actually intended to do, so it depended on if the line was supposed to be interpreted as `++(*p)++` or `++*(p++)`. The former implies the intent of incrementing by two, while the latter implies the intent of incrementing the value pointed to and then incrementing the value held by the pointer itself (which is, assumedly, what user302520 actually wants to do. I just had a mental glitch and thought it was the first case.)

Comment: `++*p++` is *not* undefined behavior because the operator precedence  causes the sub-expressions expressions to bind like so: `++(*(p++))`. So there are two different things being modified - the 'pointee' by the prefix increment and the pointer by the postfix increment.  That said, I think it's still a very poor expression to use since it's a bit of a puzzle figuring out. I think the advice of breaking it apart is good.

Comment: @Michael: It's a puzzle itself. The problem was to interpret this puzzle.