# Segmentation fault while using char * string but not with char string[11]

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when I try to modify a string constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958222/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-i-try-to-modify-a-string-constant)

I was trying to run the following two codes and I am getting a segmentation fault with  ***file2.c*** but with  ***file1.c*** I am not getting any fault. Can somebody explain what is the difference between the following codes :

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char  string[11] = {"HelloThere"};
    string[10] = '\0';
    for(i =0;i<5;i++)
    {
        string[i] = 'a';
    }
    printf("%s\n",string);
}
```

and :

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char * string;
    string = "HelloThere";

    for(i =0;i<5;i++)
    {
        string[i] = 'a';    
    }
    printf("%s",string);

}
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: @Oli - I think this one is better: [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)  Perhaps the best question is "Why didn't the OP even bother to search first?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the assignment

```
char  string[11] = {"HelloThere"};
```

*copies* the string constant into a writable memory, while

```
char * string = "HelloThere";
```

leaves it in the read-only memory. While it is absolutely OK to write to the writable memory (duh!) writing to read-only memory is *undefined behavior*, and may trigger a crash.

Note that you do not need to specify the size of your string explicitly, unless you want to allocate more memory than is required for your string literal:

```
char  string[] = {"HelloThere"}; // <<== The size is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "HelloThere";
```

then

```
string[i] = 'a';
```

is wrong - you're trying to modify a string literal, which you can't. This results in undefined behavior, so anything can happen, including crashes.

However,

```
char sring[11] = "HelloThere";
```

creates an auto array (copying the contents of the string in it beforehands) and that's writable, it's allowed to modify their elements.